# React: Can we pass 2 forms from 2 different child components to a parent, and submit them with a button which is inside the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, components, react-props

I am trying to somehow pass the data from 2 forms and 2 different components to the parent component and then somehow console.log all of this data with a button that is inside the parent component. Then I will simply send these data to a JSON file or a dummy database.

When I press the submit button of course nothing is triggered right now because I simply don't know how to pass the function from the children to the parent. I have tried many ways, but I would appreciate it if you could show me a way to lift the state and combine the forms.
For the input, in order to pass refs, I have used React.forwardRef()

It would be easy to just have 1 big component with 1 form and then the button inside this component, but since it is a fun project, I want to learn how to implement this functionality in case I will use it in the future. You can find a screenshot on this link:

[]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/myV0N.jpg

Here we go:

**1. Parent component**

```
const BookingComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CRContainer className="booking-crcontainer">
        <CRColumn>
          <PickUpCarComponent />
        </CRColumn>
        <CRColumn>
          <CustomerInfo />
        </CRColumn>
      </CRContainer>
      <CRContainer className="booking">
        <Button type="submit" btnText="hello there" />
      </CRContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookingComponent;
```

**2. Child 1**

```
const CustomerInfo = (props) => {
  const firstlRef = useRef();
  const lastNameRef = useRef();

  const onTrigger = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log(first1Ref.current.value)
    console.log("heaheaheah");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Subtitle stitle={SubtitleLabels.customerInfo} />
      <div className="customer-info-container">
        <form onSubmit={onTrigger}>
          <div>
            <LabeledInput
              labelText={CustomerInfoLabels.firstName}
              type="text"
              inputPlaceholder={GeneralLabels.placeholder}
              ref={firstlRef}
            ></LabeledInput>
            <LabeledInput
              labelText={CustomerInfoLabels.lastName}
              type="text"
              inputPlaceholder={GeneralLabels.placeholder}
              ref={lastNameRef}
            ></LabeledInput>
          </div> ...................
```

**3. Child 2**

Haven't put the refs here yet.

```
const PickUpCarComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Subtitle stitle={SubtitleLabels.pickUp} />
      <form>
      <div className="booking-inner-container">
        <div>
          <LabeledInput labelText={"Pick-up date*"} type="date"></LabeledInput>
          <LabeledInput labelText={"Pick-up time*"} type="time"></LabeledInput>
        </div>
        <DropDown type="CarGroup" labeltext="Car Group*" attribute="name" />
        <DropDown type="RentalOffice" labeltext="Region*" attribute="region" />
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PickUpCarComponent;
```

**4. Input Component**

```
const LabeledInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { labelText, type, inputPlaceholder, onChange, className } = props;

  return (
    <div className={`input-container ${className}`}>
      <label htmlFor="labelText">{labelText}</label>
      <input
        type={type}
        placeholder={inputPlaceholder}
        onChange={onChange}
        ref={ref}
      />
    </div>
  );
});

export default LabeledInput;
```

Comment: you can use context  in parent component and use it in the childs , in that context you can pass handler that child component call it. or you can pass event handlers directly to child component and handle onchange in parent component

Comment: How could I implement the second version? How can I pass the props in order to do that? Could you provide me an example? Because I know how it goes, I also mentioned it above. But I lack the way to implement it.

Comment: Maybe you could make an answer with a snippet @HDM91

Answer (score 1):

you can use context to pass form handlers to child component then in the child component you can useContext and get value and handlers of parent form and use them.

```
const FormContext = React.createContext({});

const BookingComponent = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState();
  
  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    //handle child event in parent and save child state in
    //parent to use later in submit button
  }, []); //set dependency if it's needed

  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({ handleChange }), [handleChange]);

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <div>
        <CRContainer className="booking-crcontainer">
          <CRColumn>
            <PickUpCarComponent />
          </CRColumn>
          <CRColumn>
            <CustomerInfo />
          </CRColumn>
        </CRContainer>
        <CRContainer className="booking">
          <Button type="submit" btnText="hello there" />
        </CRContainer>
      </div>
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};

const LabeledInput = (props) => {
  const formContext = useContext(FormContext);
  const { labelText, type, inputPlaceholder, className } = props;

  return (
    <div className={`input-container ${className}`}>
      <label htmlFor="labelText">{labelText}</label>
      <input
        type={type}
        placeholder={inputPlaceholder}
        onChange={formContext.handleChange}
        ref={ref}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Ahaaaa! I will try to implement it tomorrow morning and I will tag you. Thanks :D

Comment: be careful of handler in context and memoize it otherwise the child component always re renders in every change in parents.